# ¿Cómo puedo importar datos desde una variable con prompt y retornar esa variable en un dato que tenga en una clase creada previamente en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, poo, javascript-objeto, javascript-import, prompt

Estoy iniciando con el tema de clases en Javascript y me gustaría llenar una clase con los datos que he solicitado desde prompt al usuario desde la función dataEntry. Pero no sé como seguir luego de pedir los datos desde la función... Creo que estoy bastante perdido.

Tengo esta clase:

```
class Ingreso {
constructor(id, tipo, monto, [icono]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = tipo.toUpperCase();
    this.quantity = parseFloat(monto);
    this.icon = icono;
}
//Método type
getType() {
    return `Hola, el nombre ingresado de tu ingreso es ${this.type}`;
}
//Método quantity
getQuantity() {
    return `La cantidad del ingreso ${this.type}, es ${this.quantity}`;
}
//Método date
getIcon() {
    return `Coincides en que el ingreso de ${this.type}, es de ${this.quantity} e ingreso en la fecha ${this.icon}`;
} }
```

Esta es la función

```
function dataEntry() {
const tipo = prompt('Ingresa el tipo de ingreso');
const monto = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuánto ingresó por ' + tipo + '?'));

if (monto == "" || tipo == "") { //Se verifica que estén ambos datos tipeados
    alert('Te ha faltado un dato, prueba otra vez')
}
else if(isNaN(monto)) { //Se verifica que el valor otorgado en edad sea un número
    alert('El valor ingresado en alguno de los campos no es un número')
}
else if(monto <= 0){ //Si el número otorgado es negativo se pasa a positivo
    alert(username + ' Lamento decirte que has tipeado un número negativo en uno de los dos campos')
}
else { //Datos otorgados correctamente
    console.log('Se ingresaron: ' + tipo + ' y ' + monto + ' correctamente.')
};

const icono = ['sueldo', 'inversión', 'promocion', 'giftcard', 'aguinaldo', 'bono', 'otro'];
let selectedIcon = prompt('Ingresa un tipo de ícono: sueldo, inversión, promoción, giftcard, bono u otro. Presiona ESC si no quieres elegir un ícono para el ingreso')
    switch(selectedIcon) {
        case "sueldo":
            alert('El ícono elegido es ' + icono[0])
            break;
        case "inversión":
            alert('El ícono elegido es ' + icono[1])
            break;
        case "promocion":
            alert('El ícono elegido es ' + icono[2])
            break;
        case "giftcard":
            alert('El ícono elegido es ' + icono[3])
            break;
        case "aguinaldo":
            alert('El ícono elegido es ' + icono[4])
            break;
        case "bono":
            alert('El ícono elegido es ' + icono[5])
            break;
        case "otro":
            alert('El ícono elegido es ' + icono[6])
            break;
        default:
            alert('Hemos saltado el proceso ya que no has ingresado un valor válido')
            break;
    }
    console.log('El ícono ingresado es ' + selectedIcon) };
```

Me gustaría insertar los datos que obtuve en la función en los parámetros de una clase ingreso1, por ejemplo... Pero no encuentro como insertar los datos que obtuve de la función en la clase que creé previamente.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes modificar una clase ya definida, al menos no sin que todas las instancias de esta posteriores a la modificación se modifiquen también.

Ten en cuenta que cuando defines una clase, debes instanciarla para después poder modificarla, eso va por parte de la palabra reservada [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), si no instancias la clase, solo tendrás el objeto de la misma, es decir, no podrá guardar objetos ni información en una misma instancia, al modificar el objeto de la clase, se modificarán todas las instancias.

Además, no tienes que alargar tanto el código en la función `dataEntry`, solo te basta usando [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
function dataEntry() {
    const tipo = prompt('Ingresa el tipo de ingreso');
    const monto = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuánto ingresó por ' + tipo + '?'));

    if (monto == "" || tipo == "") { //Se verifica que estén ambos datos tipeados
        alert('Te ha faltado un dato, prueba otra vez')
    } else if (isNaN(monto)) { //Se verifica que el valor otorgado en edad sea un número
        alert('El valor ingresado en alguno de los campos no es un número')
    } else if (monto <= 0) { //Si el número otorgado es negativo se pasa a positivo
        alert(username + ' Lamento decirte que has tipeado un número negativo en uno de los dos campos')
    } else { //Datos otorgados correctamente
        console.log('Se ingresaron: ' + tipo + ' y ' + monto + ' correctamente.')
    };

    const icono = ['sueldo', 'inversión', 'promocion', 'giftcard', 'aguinaldo', 'bono', 'otro'];
    let selectedIcon = prompt('Ingresa un tipo de ícono: '+icono.join(", ").replace(", otro", " u otro.")+' Presiona ESC si no quieres elegir un ícono para el ingreso')
    if (icono.includes(selectedIcon)) {
      alert('El ícono elegido es ' + selectedIcon)
    } else {
      alert('Hemos saltado el proceso ya que no has ingresado un valor válido')
    }
    console.log('El ícono ingresado es ' + selectedIcon)
}

dataEntry();
```

Ahora bien, teniendo la información de la función `dataEntry`, vamos a instanciar la clase y proveerle información (la misma que obtuvimos) para que la procese

```
const instancia = new Ingreso(123, tipo, monto, selectedIcon);
```

Y a partir de esta instancia puedes usar los métodos definidos en tu clase

```
instancia.getType()
instancia.getQuantity()
instancia.getIcon()
```

Por otro lado, veo que tienes un error de sintaxis en la definición del constructor, exactamente en donde dice `[icon]`

Debería ser `icon` en vez de `[icon]`. Siendo de la segunda manera recibes un array y eso es lo que dará la consola, claro que como es de un solo elemento, la consola lo convierte a string, sin embargo, podría traerte problemas si esperas más de un elemento.

Finalmente tenemos este código

```js
class Ingreso {
    constructor(id, tipo, monto, [icono]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = tipo.toUpperCase();
        this.quantity = parseFloat(monto);
        this.icon = icono;
    }
    //Método type
    getType() {
        return `Hola, el nombre ingresado de tu ingreso es ${this.type}`;
    }
    //Método quantity
    getQuantity() {
        return `La cantidad del ingreso ${this.type}, es ${this.quantity}`;
    }
    //Método date
    getIcon() {
        return `Coincides en que el ingreso de ${this.type}, es de ${this.quantity} e ingreso en la fecha ${this.icon}`;
    }
}

function dataEntry() {
    const tipo = prompt('Ingresa el tipo de ingreso');
    const monto = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuánto ingresó por ' + tipo + '?'));

    if (monto == "" || tipo == "") { //Se verifica que estén ambos datos tipeados
        alert('Te ha faltado un dato, prueba otra vez')
    } else if (isNaN(monto)) { //Se verifica que el valor otorgado en edad sea un número
        alert('El valor ingresado en alguno de los campos no es un número')
    } else if (monto <= 0) { //Si el número otorgado es negativo se pasa a positivo
        alert(username + ' Lamento decirte que has tipeado un número negativo en uno de los dos campos')
    } else { //Datos otorgados correctamente
        console.log('Se ingresaron: ' + tipo + ' y ' + monto + ' correctamente.')
    };

    const icono = ['sueldo', 'inversión', 'promocion', 'giftcard', 'aguinaldo', 'bono', 'otro'];
    let selectedIcon = prompt('Ingresa un tipo de ícono: '+icono.join(", ").replace(", otro", " u otro.")+' Presiona ESC si no quieres elegir un ícono para el ingreso')
    if (icono.includes(selectedIcon)) {
      alert('El ícono elegido es ' + selectedIcon)
    } else {
      alert('Hemos saltado el proceso ya que no has ingresado un valor válido')
    }
    console.log('El ícono ingresado es ' + selectedIcon)
    console.log("Instanciando la clase");
    const instancia = new Ingreso(123, tipo, monto, selectedIcon);
    console.log(
      instancia.getType(),
      instancia.getQuantity(),
      instancia.getIcon()
    );
}

dataEntry();
```

Te dejo algunos enlazes de referencia:

- [JavaScript orientado a objetos para principiantes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS)
- [Programación orientada a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos)